# how to change List view for Parse JSONarray inside JSONarray in android? changes in list view

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, url

I recently asked the question regarding android Json error No value for variation_id?

so i am using the answer of that in [this example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/)

but here i am unable to parse images because.

in the example images are not the array. they are in JSONObject.. so i am parsing them in 
like

```
JSONObject il = vo.getJSONObject("flag");
map.put("flag", il.optString("flag"));
```

But i have this in inside a array.. so i am parsing this like

```
JSONArray flag = c.getJSONArray("flag ");
 for(int s=0;s<flag .length();s++)
  {
  System.out.println("URL"+flag .getString(s));
  }
```

Till here Imageloader.java file is also clear.. as it is avaliable [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/)

But Before that its entering into ListViewAdapter.java

you can see the entire source code(imageloader,ListviewAdaper) at [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/)

SO at the List view 
Image is declaring as an object like

```
 intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
 // Start SingleItemView Class
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

SO i want it for a JSONARRAY
i am unable to reach please help..

Comment: Post the full stacktrace, or find out the place you accessing the variation_id from JSON

Comment: hellow  Rajesh CP sir.. please change that listviewadapter.java in that only images which is diclaring as JSONObject.. so i want to change it to JSONArray.. Please refer this site for those two http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/ my coding is so huge so i am unable to ask a question with that.. but  i followed this site to parse entire data except images..